# Calling function defined in GameScene from an NSTimer in GameViewController

Tags: ios, swift

In my GameViewController.swift I have a function called resumeGameScene. In that function I start 3 timers. All of which call 3 separate functions (lane1,lane2, and lane3) in my GameScene.swift file. I've tried the making my functions class functions but this didn't work because I have more functions and variables inside these functions (lane1, lane2, and lane3).

**GameViewController.swift:**

```
    func resumeGameScene() {
    if (GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene) != nil
    {
        let skView = self.view as! SKView

        if skView.scene != nil
        {
            skView.paused = false

            if resumeTime1 != nil && resumeTime2 != nil && resumeTime3 != nil
            {

                timer1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(resumeTime1!, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.lane1), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

                timer2 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(resumeTime2!, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.lane2), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

                timer3 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(resumeTime3!, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.lane3), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)



            }

        }
    }
}
```

**GameScene.swift:**

```
func lane1()
{


    let randomNum = arc4random_uniform(100) + 1

    levels()

    if randomNum < 46
    {
        mouseFire(1, laneFire: fire)

    }
    else
    {
        enemyFire(1, laneFire: fire)

    }

}//End of lane1 func


func lane2()
{

    let randomNum = arc4random_uniform(100) + 1

    levels()

    if randomNum < 46
    {
        mouseFire(3, laneFire: fire)

    }
    else
    {
        enemyFire(3, laneFire: fire)

    }

}//End of Lane2 func


func lane3()
{


    let randomNum = arc4random_uniform(100) + 1

    levels()

    if randomNum < 46
    {
        mouseFire(5, laneFire: fire)

    }
    else
    {
        enemyFire(5, laneFire: fire)

    }

}//End of Lane3 func
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target is `self` hence selector will be invoked on `self` which is `GameViewController`. Since your selector is not in `GameViewController` thus this will not work. You need to create object of `GameScene` and pass it to target.

Comment: Thanks! How do you create an object of GameScene and pass it to the target? Sorry I'm a new coder